# Deleting spaces from the beginning of strings

Tags: c++, string

I have a vector of strings, now how can I delete all spaces from the BEGINNING of each string.
For example: `v{"   abc  ", "dd e f", "   b a  "}`, after deleting: `v{"abc  ", "dd e f", "bb a  "}`

Comment: did you try something? Do you know how to remove leading spaces from a single string?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: `std::string::find_first_not_of`.

Comment: I tried with erase, but I failed